# Add textbox and text/chip dynamically in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add textbox (max 10) dynamically with a close (X) button and then want to add some text to it. Text should show in different view after click Save button. Added textbox or text should be removable if click on the close button (X).

The view can toggle with an edit\close button.

[image: Add text box and text/chip dynamically in Angular 5]

Comment: This is one of the first items described at https://angular.io/tutorial - Angular's Tour of Heroes and even has example code that literally does this.

Comment: Thre is a slight difference, I want to add textbox first and then want to add text to it. Angular's Tour of Heroes is having only one textbox to add chips.

Comment: Go ahead and update your question to show relevant code that you've attempted, and the difference between that and what you would like to achieve. As your question stands it does match exactly, so in order to provide you with help you will need to make these changes (or it will likely be automatically closed due to being too broad).

Comment: Thanks, @Z.Bagley for your time and comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**app.component.ts**

```
  fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
  newAttribute: any = {};

  firstField = true;
  firstFieldName = 'First Item name';
  isEditItems: boolean;

  addFieldValue(index) {
    if (this.fieldArray.length <= 2) {
      this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute);
      this.newAttribute = {};
    } else {

    }
  }

  deleteFieldValue(index) {
    this.fieldArray.splice(index, 1);
  }

  onEditCloseItems() {
    this.isEditItems = !this.isEditItems;
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered col-lg-4">
      <caption><i>Add/remove textbox and chip dynamically in Angular 6</i></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item Name
                        <a (click)="onEditCloseItems()" class="text-info float-right">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-{{isEditItems ? 'close' : 'pencil'}} mdi-18px"></i>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody *ngIf="!isEditItems">
                <tr *ngIf="firstField">
                    <td>
                        <i (click)="firstField = false" class="mdi mdi-close mdi-18px"></i> {{firstFieldName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
                    <td *ngIf="field?.name">
                        <i (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)" class="mdi mdi-close mdi-18px"></i> {{field.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody *ngIf="isEditItems">
                <tr>
                    <td *ngIf="firstField">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div (click)="firstField = false" class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-close mdi-18px"></i></div>
                            </div>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="firstFieldName" class="form-control py-2 " type="text" name="firstFieldName" placeholder="Item Name">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)" class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-close mdi-18px"></i></div>
                            </div>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="field.name" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{field.name}}" placeholder="Item Name">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <button *ngIf="fieldArray.length <= 2" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" (click)="addFieldValue()" style="margin-right:10px">Add More Item</button>
                        <button (click)="onEditCloseItems()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Save Items</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz demo link 1](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ka8zxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Edited**
[Stackblitz demo link 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iabn9x?embed=1&file=src/main.ts)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful example